# Failure to register comments without login

Tags: python, html, django, authentication, comments

Comments are registered on the desired page, and for people who aren't logged in, if they want to leave a comment, it says to enter the site first, but later the comments are registered under the name AnonymousUser. I don't want this registration to happen.
Which part and how should be edited?

in views.py:

```
comments = Comment.objects.filter(product=product)

if request.method == 'POST':

    # comment

    if 'comment' in request.POST:
        author = request.user
        content = request.POST.get('content')
        comment = Comment(product=product, author=author, content=content)
        comment.save()


context = {
        'comments': comments, 
        }



return render(request, 'auctions/product_detail.html', context)
```

in product_detail.html:

```
<h3 id="h3">Comments</h3>

    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <ul>
            {% for comment in comments %}
                <li><a>{{ comment.author }} : {{comment.content}}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
       </ul>   
    {% else %}
       Not signed in.
    {% endif %}
```

`

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if user.is_authenticated` is only in the template, so you're only deciding whether to show the comments to users based on their authentication status.

In your django views there is always a user associated with the request. If they're not logged in it's just an anonymous user.

You have a couple of options:

1. You put authentication checks on the view so that only logged in users can access the view at all.
2. You check the authentication status of the user when the view is POSTed (which you're not doing at all - this is where you check if it is a POST), and if they are not logged in, the validation fails and no changes (i.e. new comments) are submitted. You also set some kind of failure message so the user knows they have to log in to make a comment.

Where you need to be doing this is in your view code:

```
    if 'comment' in request.POST:
        author = request.user
        if author.is_authenticated:
            content = request.POST.get('content')
            comment = Comment(product=product, author=author, content=content)
            comment.save()
```

Currently this saves comments regardless of who has added them. You have the `request.user` here, so you need to check the `is_authenticated` value before you do the save - just don't save if they are not authenticated (I also suggest you use the messages framework to inform the user their comment wasn't saved because they need to log in, but that's extra and entirely up to you).

Comment: thanks,Normally, all users should be able to see the products and enter the site only to buy and leave comments.
The comments of people who are not logged in should not be registered either. I have no idea of ​​the code. Can you tell me the code?

Comment: @michjnich did a very good job here.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're allowing comments to be posted by users who are not logged in, but you want to prevent these comments from being attributed to an "AnonymousUser." To achieve this, you should check whether the user is authenticated before attempting to create a comment with their username.

Here's an updated version of what your `views.py` should look like:

```py
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, redirect, render
from django.urls import reverse


def product_detail(request, product_id):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, pk=product_id)
    comments = Comment.objects.filter(product=product)

    if request.method == 'POST' and 'comment' in request.POST:
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            # Redirect to the login page, appending the 'next' parameter to the
            # URL helps redirect the user back to the product detail page after
            # the user is successfully authenticated
            login_url = reverse('login')
            return redirect(f"{login_url}?next={request.get_full_path()}")

        author = request.user
        content = request.POST.get('content')
        comment = Comment(product=product, author=author, content=content)
        comment.save()

    context = {
        'comments': comments,
    }

    return render(request, 'auctions/product_detail.html', context)
```

This way, if a user is not logged in and tries to post a comment, they will be prompted to log in first, and the comment won't be saved as an "AnonymousUser." After the user is authenticated successfully, the user is sent back to the product detail page they were trying to comment on.

Comment: Thanks but This code returns this error: Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/?next=/product_detail1
Using the URLconf defined in commerce.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
[name='index']
login [name='login']
logout [name='logout']
register [name='register']
product_detail<int:product_id> [name='product_detail']
category<int:category_id> [name='category']
^media/(?P<path>.*)$
The current path, accounts/login/, didn’t match any of these.

Comment: And the person must be able to see the product information by logging in. He must log in only to buy and comment. In this case, without logging in, he cannot see the product information.

Comment: Got you, please check the updated code in my answer.

Comment: that's right.thanks so much.